# Reward(t) vs. Reward(t+1) ? Reinforcement Learning, Q-learning

Tags: reinforcement-learning, q-learning

In ["Reinforcement Learning, An Introduction; Richard S. Sutton and Andrew G. Barto"](http://incompleteideas.net/book/RLbook2018.pdf) is written on page 70:

**3.1  The Agent–Environment Interface**

> At each time step t, the agent receives some representation of the
> environment’s state State(t), and on that basis selects an action
> A(t). **One time step later**, in  part **as a consequence of its action**,
> the agent receives a numerical **reward R(t+1)**,  and finds itself in a
> new state S(t+1).
>
> [4] We use R(t+1) instead of R(t) to denote the reward due to A(t)
> because it emphasizes that the next reward and next state, R(t+1) and
> S(t+1), are jointly determined.  Unfortunately, both conventions are
> widely used in the literature.

**In case of trading a reward for opening a SELL(-1)/NONE(0)/BUY(1) could look like this:**

```
reward = self.direction * (self.price[t+1] - self.price[t])
```

We step t+1 into the future...

However, i often see people doing it different: [Q-Trader](https://github.com/edwardhdlu/q-trader/blob/master/train.py)

```
for t in xrange(l):
        action = agent.act(state)

        # sit
        next_state = getState(data, t + 1, window_size + 1)
        reward = 0

        if action == 1: # buy
            agent.inventory.append(data[t])
            print "Buy: " + formatPrice(data[t])

        elif action == 2 and len(agent.inventory) > 0: # sell
            bought_price = agent.inventory.pop(0)
            reward = max(data[t] - bought_price, 0)
            total_profit += data[t] - bought_price
            print "Sell: " + formatPrice(data[t]) + " | Profit: " + formatPrice(data[t] - bought_price)
```

He's clearly using the current Price(t) for OPEN/CLOSE. And for the CLOSE that makes sense to me, as he's closing the trade NOW at Price(t) and NOT at Price(t+1), so the reward is Price(current)-Price(open)...

I somehow get confused because in one case the next value is used, in the other case the current. For opening a position the first way (t+1) makes more sense to me "self.direction * (self.price[t+1] - self.price[t])" as we are interested in the next value. But for closing it, we need the current value.

**Question:** Can i use both versions, OPEN rewards are R(t+1) and CLOSE rewards are R(t)? Is this a valid approach?

Thanks!

Comment: no ideas or hints?